# Is it bad to add your postgres connection directly in your graphql resolver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, graphql

If I wanted to use the lower level Postgres package from NPM called [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) inside my Apollo server so I don't have to use an ORM. Is it considered bad practice to pass the connection into the resolver directly?

Example:

```js
// ./db/index.ts

import { Pool } from 'pg'

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'your_username',
  host: 'your_host',
  database: 'your_database',
  password: 'your_password',
  port: 5432,
});

export default pool
```

```js
// ./index.ts

import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server'
import pool from './db'

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    getUsers: [User]
  }

  type User {
    id: ID
    name: String
    email: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getUsers: async () => {
      const result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users');
      return result.rows;
    },
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Server running at ${url}`);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass into the resolver"? I don't see your code passing around a connection anywhere.

Comment: This line inside of the getUsers query I'm using `pool`

`const result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users');`

Say if I had a folder with a bunch of different resolvers, would it be considered bad practice to `import pool from '../db'` in each resolver file or should I pass the pool on the Apollo Server context object allowing me to access the pool in every resolver or should I build a DBConnection class and instantiate a new database connection in every resolver file?

Comment: It depends on your needs. Passing the pool via the context object is a simple form of dependency injection, which would e.g. easily allow passing a mock during tests. The more important issue though is that you should not pass the pool, to have every resolver acquire its own connection/client, but rather you should use one connection per query (optionally even wrapped in a transaction) and pass that into your resolvers - ideally, through the context.